# Pazy's book: Negation of $\overline{\lim}_{x\uparrow a}|f(x)|<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I was reading the proof of Theorem 6.2.2., [Pazy, Semigroups of Linear Operators...Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-5561-1) and confused.

Essentially we want to show ${\lim}_{x\uparrow a}|f(x)|=\infty$. I believe by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Infinite_limits) this means that

> For any $K>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that ($x\in D(f)$, $0\leq a-x<\delta $ $\implies$ $K<|f(x)|$),

where by $D(f)$ I mean the domain of $f$. (It may be the case that ${\lim}_{x\uparrow a}$ means ${\lim}_{x\uparrow a,x\neq a}$, but it does not seem to matter here. )

So negating this readily gives us

> For any $\delta >0$ there exists $K>0$ such that ($x\in D(f)$, $0\leq a-x<\delta $ $\implies$ $K\geq |f(x)|$)

What is confusing me is that in the aforementioned proof, we first negate essentially $\overline{\lim}_{x\uparrow a}|f(x)|=\infty$ to get $|f(x)|\leq K$ for (basically) any $x$. (In the following proof I am looking at $\overline{\lim}_{t\uparrow t_{\mathrm{max}}}\|u(t)\|=\infty$)

[image]

and then to show ${\lim}_{t\uparrow t_{\mathrm{max}}}\|u(t)\|<\infty$ we negate ${\lim}_{t\uparrow t_{\mathrm{max}}}\|u(t)\|=\infty$ to get

> there is a sequence $t_n\uparrow t_{\mathrm{max}}$ and a constant $K$ such that $\|u(t_n)\|\leq K$ for all $n$

and derive contradiction using the continuity of $t\mapsto \|u(t)\|$.
[image]

But don't we have ${\lim}_{t\uparrow t_{\mathrm{max}}}\|u(t)\|=\infty$ already when we say the negation of $\overline{\lim}_{t\uparrow t_{\mathrm{max}}}\|u(t)\|=\infty$ in the proof is absurd?
I thought unlike the usual definition of limit, $\lim...=\infty$ does not require the subtlety of existence of the limit but Pazy seems to be distinguishing limsup and lim for this case as well and I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Your first quantified statement reads $$\forall K > 0 \quad \exists \delta > 0 \quad \forall x \in D(f) \quad 0 \le x-a < \delta \implies K < |f(x)|.$$

You didn't negate it correctly. The proper negation is
$$ \exists K > 0 \quad \forall \delta > 0 \quad \exists x \in D(f) \quad 0 \le x-a  < \delta\quad  \& \quad K \ge |f(x)|.$$

Your statement "$|f(x)| \le K$ for (basically) any $x$" isn't true due to the existential quantifier on $x$.

Comment: I see, so the sequence $t_n$ can be obtained by $\delta_n\to 0$ and the corresponding existing $t_n$.

Comment: And for the limsup, 
$\limsup_{x\uparrow a} |f(x)|=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\big(\sup\{|f(x)|\mid x\in D(f), 0<a-x<\epsilon \}\big)=\infty$  
iff  
$\forall K>0\;\exists\delta>0\; \forall\epsilon>0,\, \epsilon<\delta \implies \sup\{|f(x)|\mid x\in D(f), 0<a-x<\epsilon \}>K$,  
so the negation yields  
$\exists K>0\; \forall \delta>0\; \exists\epsilon>0,\, \epsilon<\delta,  \sup\{|f(x)|\mid x\in D(f), 0<a-x<\epsilon \}\leq K$.

Comment: So for some $\epsilon^*$ we have $  \sup\{|f(x)|\mid x\in D(f), x\in [a-\epsilon^*/2,a)] \}\leq K$ but from the continuity of $|f(\cdot)|$ (but the continuity is not explicitly used to say the boundedness on $0\leq t<t_{\mathrm{max}}$) we have $\sup_{x\in[0,a-\epsilon^*/2]}|f(x)|\leq \max_{x\in[0,a-\epsilon^*/2]}|f(x)|$  and thus all good?